# Is there a way to request microphone access for a chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm currently playing around with WebKit speech API and trying to implement it in a chrome extension. Unfortunately, I'm having many troubles with getting the typical pop up that appears when a site asks for microphone permission (allowing you to accept or decline). Any idea on how to accomplish this? I have a div which triggers the web speech recognition function on click. Thanks so much! All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native method [`getUserMedia`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) is what you want, and don't forget to declare `audioCapture` permissions.